# ObjectId and find in moongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

To find an item

```
Products.findOne({"_id":"123456"}, callback);
```

To find few item I have to do

```
Products.find({"_id":{$in:[ObjectId("123456"),ObjectId("7891011")]}}, callback);
```

but why I need to use ObjectId() in the second query? The first one worked without using ObjectId(), both of **their schema is the same**.

Comment: Because the item is of type string you will need to explicitly convert it wherever you are building that array.
If you are using mongoose  then try this
to each of your array element
mongoose.type.ObjectId(arr[i]);
And then do this:
Products.find({"_id":{$in:arr]}}, callback);

Comment: When you are using the mongoose at nodejs server then no need to use ObjectId while finding through _id. Just use fully updated mongodb and mongoose and try the same.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert to ObjectId's if you are using mongooose in node,
when you work with aggregate you might need to convert it to ObjectId.

```
 var toMongoObjectId = function (ids) {
     return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
       if (ids.constructor === Array) {
         resolve(ids.map(mongoose.Types.ObjectId));
       }
       resolve(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(ids));
 })
}
```

## convert to ObjectId

```
toMongoObjectId(ids).then(function(ObjectIds){
         //ObjectIds
})
```